# What are the advantages of using the Pointer type in Pascal?

Tags: pointers, pascal

I assume that the Pointer type is a wrapper for simple pointers in modern Pascal. I didn't find any information about this type. All I know is that when I declare my pointer as `x: Pointer` instead of `x: ^Integer` I don't have to specify the type of the pointer. Is this the only thing that makes the Pointer type better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pointer type is untyped and assignment compatible with all other pointer types (assign typed pointer to "pointer" without cast). Mostly comparable with void* behaviour in C.

In Turbo Pascal it also prevented accidental dereference (a:pointer; something:=a^) was illegal. In Delphi that was relaxed to return a byte, I have no idea why.